# How to extract Synopsys .tz files on ubuntu

Tags: extract

I have downloaded some tar fies for my CAD tools( from their site ). When I extracted my tar, it gave out .tz files. How can I extract files from them or isn't it a tar archive ? 
Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide the link..

Comment: Actually the link is related to synopsys (CAD tool ) download section which can only be accessed through authentication ( which I don't have). My Professor has provided me the files and and he has asked me to install those files.

Comment: I think tou have tried this too right: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/tz thank you, for your patience.

Comment: I tried everything that I found over google. Actually you have 2 ways of installing those files, first is through a gui provided by synopsys and secondly you can directly extract the files and place it accordingly. I always prefer the second way , earlier they provided files in tar format, that was ok, but now there are files in .tz format that's where I got stuck. Anywayz now I'll try the first method. Thanks

Comment: Can you do a `file [name of your .tz file here]` and add the result to your question ?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Gui ,I got the files installed. Later on I checked the tcl script that is working behind the gui. In that script, they renamed the file to `.taz` , then added/appended some details to the file using some function. After which , I could extract the file using

```
zcat filename | tar -xvf-
```

or using

```
gzip -d filname.taz | tar -xvf-
```

or directly

```
tar -xvf filename.taz
```

I think since this is a file related to a proprietary tool, they have some sort of encryption script which is to be run to make the file a tar archive. In the earlier versions they directly gave the tar file.

Answer (score 0):

You can open .tz files using the archive manger pre - installed in Ubuntu. But you need to have the p7zip package installed.

Comment: its already installed, I have tried using p7zip as p7zip -d filename but the result is  "--unknown suffix ignored". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this command: tar -xvf file.tz ?

Comment: yes.It is not working. I have checked the type of the file using "file" it is displaying as ":data". Does that mean its a sort of binary

Answer (score 0):

Try: `tar xf yourfile.tz`

Synopsys archives are usually gzipped tar archives, but since `file` just shows your file type as `data` it seems you might have something else. Read the Synopsys Install instructions, and verify the files you got have been downloaded and copied correctly. Another possibility is that the files might have been encrypted, this will be noted on either the download site or in the install instructions.

Comment: As stated above, using the Gui ,I got the files installed, later on I checked the tcl script that is working behing the gui. 
In that script, they renamed the file to .taz , then added/appended some details to the file using some function. After which , I could extract the file using **" zcat filename | tar -xvf- " or using gzip -d filname.taz | tar -xvf- " or directly " tar -xvf filename.taz"**

I think since this is a file related to a proprietary tool , so they have some sort of encryption script which is to be run to make the file a tar archive. 
**Thank you guys for your interest

Comment: Glad that you got it working, you should put that as the answer and mark it accepted in case anyone else ever has this problem and is looking for a solution.

Comment: Since I am a new user I got to wait for 8 hrs more to answer my own question :( . I would surely post the answer